# Get parent class using the child

Tags: c#

I have two classes which one is the generalization of the other:

```
public class son: parent { ... }
```

Then, I have a function that receives an generic object, which their type is `son`:

```
public void func(object son) {...}
```

What I want, is a way to extract the `parent` part from the `object son`

Comment: your function does not get a generic object, just an `object`. Just  get `func(son s)` or better if all you need is the parent then ask for the `parent` instead of `son`....

Comment: `public void func(parent son) {...}`

Comment: Also, using the sun, what you will get will only be light or heat :).

Comment: @benichka sorry :) I need  to pay more attention

Comment: Also, learn about naming conventions. Classes use Pascal case, so Your classes should be named `Parent` and `Son`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify what kind of object is son and then extract Parent by casting it such as this:

```
public void func(T son) where T: Parent
{...}
```

Here object son is of type Parent and you can extract the relevant information you need.